# CSS: How to "merge" search icon with text so that it will disappear when typing inside

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how I can "merge" the 'search icon' with the text ("Search here..") in the input box so that when I click inside the input box and type that not only the text but also the icon would disappear. I also want that the icon would have the same color as the "Search here.." text.

Thanks!

```css
  body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
  }


  a.nounderline{
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;

  }


  div.container{
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #000;

  }

  a.nounderline span {
  color: #00B200;
}

  .topnav input[type=text] {
    float: left;
    padding: 4.5px;
    padding-left: 28px;
    width: 305px;
    border: 2px solid #00B200;
    border-radius: 18px;
    outline: inherit;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 115px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    direction: inherit;

  }

  input::placeholder {
    color: #BEBEBE;
  }

  span.topnav {
right: 50px;

}
```

```html
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
      <div class="container">
          <a href="index.html" class="nounderline">Hello</a>
      </div>
    </header>
    

    <div class="topnav">
  <input style="position:relative;" type="text" name: "searchText" placeholder="Search here.." maxlength="18">
  <span style="position:absolute; left: 126px; top: 119px;" class="fa fa-search icon"></span>
  </div>





</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need such a result?

```js
input_text = document.querySelector('.topnav > input');
input_loop = document.querySelector('.fa.fa-search.icon');

input_text.oninput = function() {
  if (this.value == '' || this.value == this.defaultValue) {
      input_loop.classList.remove('close_loop');
      this.classList.remove('cursor_left');
  } else {
      input_loop.classList.add('close_loop');
      this.classList.add('cursor_left');
  }
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
  }


  a.nounderline{
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;

  }


  div.container{
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #000;

  }

  a.nounderline span {
  color: #00B200;
}

  .topnav input[type=text] {
    float: left;
    padding: 4.5px;
    padding-left: 28px;
    width: 305px;
    border: 2px solid #00B200;
    border-radius: 18px;
    outline: inherit;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 115px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    direction: inherit;
    
    transition: .3s;

  }

  input::placeholder {
    color: #BEBEBE;
  }
  
  .fa-search:before {
    color: #BEBEBE;
}

  span.topnav {
right: 50px;

}

.close_loop {
 display: none!important;
}

.cursor_left {
 padding-left: 10px!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



  <body>

    <header>
      <div class="container">
          <a href="index.html" class="nounderline">Hello</a>
      </div>
    </header>
    

    <div class="topnav">
  <input style="position:relative;" type="text" name: "searchText" placeholder="Search here.." maxlength="18">
  <span style="position:absolute; left: 126px; top: 119px;" class="fa fa-search icon"></span>
  </div>



</body>
```

Comment: almost. The blinking cursor just needs to start at the 'search icon' and not at the "S" of "Search here..". Thanks

Comment: The blinking cursor is still at the 'S' of "Search here..". But I need it at at the beginning of the icon.

Comment: ...but in my solution, the blinking cursor starts from the location of the icon. Show screenshot of where the blinking cursor should appear

Comment: Fixed this. Check

Comment: Thanks man! But can u please reverse it again? I thought it will look better like that, but it does not ahaha

Comment: reverse my default answer?

Comment: The last thing that u changed (where I sent u the screen), please reverse this again.

Comment: If you have any more wishes or requests, then tell me about it. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subsequent-sibling Combination to hide the icon when the text box is in focus.

```css
body{
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #fff;
      }


      a.nounderline{
        text-decoration: none;
        outline: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;

      }


      div.container{
        text-align: center;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 5px;
        background-color: #000;

      }

      a.nounderline span {
      color: #00B200;
    }

      .topnav input[type=text] {
        float: left;
        padding: 4.5px;
        padding-left: 28px;
        width: 305px;
        border: 2px solid #00B200;
        border-radius: 18px;
        outline: inherit;
        margin-top: 80px;
        margin-left: 115px;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 18px;
        direction: inherit;

      }

      input::placeholder {
        color: #BEBEBE;
      }

      span.topnav {
    right: 50px;

    }
#my-search-box:focus ~ 
#fa-search-icon {
 opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out; 
}
```

```html
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
      </head>

      <body>

        <header>
          <div class="container">
              <a href="index.html" class="nounderline">Hello</a>
          </div>
        </header>
        

        <div class="topnav">
      <input id="my-search-box" style="position:relative;" type="text" name: "searchText" placeholder="Search here.." maxlength="18">
      <span id="fa-search-icon" style="position:absolute; left: 126px; top: 119px;" class="fa fa-search icon"></span>
      </div>





    </html>
```

Comment: Can you make the blinking cursor to start at the beginning of the input box and not at the 'S' of the "Search here.." . Thank you!